# AEM (6.3) RTE Component not showing image plugin in touch UI

Tags: richtextbox, aem, aem-6

I'm adding the RTE component into a dialog in AEM:

```
<richtext
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/richtext"
        fieldLabel="Richtext"
        name="./richtext"
        useFixedInlineToolbar="{Boolean}true">
    <rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <format
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                features="*"/>
        <justify
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                features="*"/>
        <lists
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                features="*"/>
        <paraformat
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                features="*"/>
        <links
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                features="*"/>
        <image
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                features="*"/>
    </rtePlugins>
    <uiSettings jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <cui jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <inline
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    toolbar="[format#bold,format#italic,format#underline,#justify,#lists,subsuperscript#subscript,subsuperscript#superscript,links#modifylink,links#unlink,links#anchor,#image,findreplace#find,findreplace#replace,spellcheck#checktext,misctools#specialchars,misctools#sourceedit,#styles,#paraformat,table#table]">
                <popovers jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <justify
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            items="[justify#justifyleft,justify#justifycenter,justify#justifyright]"
                            ref="justify"/>
                    <lists
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            items="[lists#unordered,lists#ordered,lists#outdent,lists#indent]"
                            ref="lists"/>
                    <paraformat
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            items="paraformat:getFormats:paraformat-pulldown"
                            ref="paraformat"/>
                    <styles
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            items="styles:getStyles:styles-pulldown"
                            ref="styles"/>
                </popovers>
            </inline>
        </cui>
    </uiSettings>
</richtext>
```

But when check the dialog in authoring mode, the image plugin isn't present:
[image]

I'm wondering if is enough to just add the pluging in the dialog or there is no support in AEM (6.3) for images in RTE component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Considering that the image plugin provides only basic image support (drag from content or Content Finder), you need not have to rely on it to author images in RTE. With `useFixedInlineToolbar` property which you are already using, the richtext resourceType allows you to drag and drop images from the content finder onto the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to change #image to image#imageProps in the toolbar property to make it show up in the RTE toolbar.

```
<inline
 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
 toolbar="[format#bold,format#italic,format#underline,#justify,#lists,subsuperscript#subscript,subsuperscript#superscript,links#modifylink,links#unlink,links#anchor,image#imageProps,findreplace#find,findreplace#replace,spellcheck#checktext,misctools#specialchars,misctools#sourceedit,#styles,#paraformat,table#table]">
```

Comment: Well is appearing now, but is disabled

Comment: Does it become enabled as soon as you click on an inline image in the RTE?

Comment: It seems it becomes available when I drag and drop an image from the content finder, now is working.